# Lua: Doing arithmetic in for k,v in pairs(tbl) loops

Tags: math, for-loop, lua, lua-table

I have a table such as the following:

```
mafiadb:{"Etzli":{"alive":50,"mafia":60,"vigilante":3,"doctor":4,"citizen":78,"police":40},"Charneus":{"alive":29,"mafia":42,"vigilante":6,"doctor":14,"citizen":53,"police":33}}
```

There are more nested tables, but I'm just trying to keep it simple for now.

I run the following code to extract certain values (I'm making an ordered list based on those values):

```
sortmaf={}
for k,v in pairs(mafiadb) do
sortmaf[k]=v["mafia"]
end
```

That's one of the codes I run.  The problem I'm running into is that it doesn't appear you can do arithmetic in a table loop.  I tried:

```
sortpct={}
for k,v in pairs(mafiadb) do
sortpct[k]=(v["alive"]*100)/(v["mafia"]+v["vigilante"]+v["doctor"]+v["citizen"]+v["police"])
end
```

It returns that I'm attempting to do arithmetic on field "alive."  What am I missing here?  As usual, I appreciate any consideration in answering this question!

Editing:
Instead of commenting on the comment, I'm going to add additional information here.

The mafiadb database I've posted IS the real database.  It's just stripped down to two players instead of the current 150+ players I have listed in it.  It's simply structured as such:

```
mafiadb = {
            Playername = {
                           alive = 0
                           mafia = 0
                           vigilante = 0
                           doctor = 0
                           police = 0
                           citizen = 0
                          }
           }
```

Add a few hundred more playernames, and there you have it.

As for the error message, the exact message is:

> attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'alive' (nil value)

So... I'm not sure what the problem is.  In my first code, the one with sortmaf, it works perfectly, but suddenly, it can't find v["alive"] as a value when I'm trying to do arithmetic?  If I just put v["alive"] by itself, it's suddenly found and isn't nil any longer.  I hope this clarifies a bit more.

Comment: Apart from the extra `{` near "Charneus", `mafiadb` and the code you posted work fine together. You most certainly can do everything in a `for` loop (the only exception being adding or removing elements from the table you are iterating over). The loop code looks fine, I'm guessing you are feeding it some non-numeric data at some point. You should post the real `mafiadb` and the exact error message to get better help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a simple typo to me.

Some of your 150 characters is not well written - probably they don't have an "alive" property, or it's written incorrectly, or it's not a number. Try this:

```
for k,v in pairs(mafiadb) do
  if type(v.alive) ~= 'number' then
    print(k, "doesn't have a correct alive property")
  end
end
```

This should print the names of the "bad" characters.

Comment: Dear lord, I feel like SUCH an idiot.  I forgot, there was ONE key that did not have any properties at all, simply because it didn't need one.  I made an if condition within that loop, and now it works perfectly...  THANKS!

Comment: You are welcome! Also, notice that you can do `v.alive` . It's the same as `v["alive"]`, and it'll save you some typing. Happy hacking!